# Безопасная передача переменной из php в js

Tags: javascript, php, xss

Как безопасно передать содержимое переменной php в переменную js при условии, что фильтрацию и экранирование символов выполнить невозможно?

Я правильно понимаю, что наиболее безопасным в этом случае является взятие  переменной через xhr/ajax-запросы (вместо обычной php-инъекции в коде)? Это будет безопасным до тех пор, пока я не использую .innerHTML и прочие подобные функции?

```
<?php
// ...
$response = ['myvar' => $var];
echo json_encode($response); 
?>
```

Js

```
$.ajax({
    url: getmyvar.php,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
        alert(res["myvar"]);
    }
});
```

Более изящного способа, не требующего дополнительного «экранирующего» запроса, не существует? (небезопасное содержимое находится в одной из переменной сессий)

Comment: Откуда такое странное условие?

Comment: условие действительно странное. если вы можете добавить код на вывод переменной, то и на её фильтрацию тоже

Comment: @bars  А что странного? Есть сервис, с которого я через oauth получаю имя юзера. Имя там практически не фильтруется, разрешены имена с <, >, длиной в 255 символов. Я не могу сделать фильтрацию строже, чем в сервисе.

Comment: Так вам и не нужна фильтрация. Вам нужно экранирование символов